# NodeJS Express routers with same route?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not able to understand why the following sample is working: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-nodejs-webapp-sample/tree/master/01-Login/routes

If you look at both routers, they expose the same route '/'. When the user is authenticated (throw Auth0), the '/callback' route of index.js router is called which is doing the following:

```
res.redirect('/user');
```

As the following is declared in app.js:

```
var user = require('./routes/user');    
app.use('/user', user);
```

, I understand that the user.js router is going to be used... but in user.js there's no '/user' route but only a '/'.

Can someone explain me how the '/' route of user.js router is used?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Though the router user.js has '/' route, you are mounting the user.js route in '/user' path. So the route '/' will be considered as '/user/'.

```
app.use('/user', user);
```

If you mount in some other path say

```
app.use('/user/sample/demo', user);
```

Then your route for user.js will be '/user/sample/demo/'.

Hope you understand the routing concept

Answer (score 0):

They inherit the base path from when they are used within the main `app.js` file

On [lines 62 and 63](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-nodejs-webapp-sample/blob/master/01-Login/app.js#L62-L63) you will find

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/user', user);
```

This means:

- any routes returned by `routes` will have a base path of `/`.
- any routes returned by `user` will have a base path of `/user`.

Its actually a very good pattern to follow in both Express or even Koa to keep your code easy to manage and update.

You can find out more regarding this pattern on the [express routing page](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), the last section called `express.Router`